# Getting all rows pre-selected by default in magento admin grid

Tags: php, magento, grid

I am getting all the rows pre-selected by default on page load in magento admin grid.

Due to this when I select fields and apply mass action error appears i.e. 'Please select items.'

For reference please find the snaps below:

All Fields are selected :

[image: All Fields are selected...]

Still getting error:

[image]

Any Kind of help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

In the mass action field I have set wrong name. Once I replaced it with the correct index name of the column the issue is resolved.

A snippet of the code is as follows:

```
parent::_prepareMassaction();
$this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
$this->setMassactionIdFilter('entity_id');
$this->setMassactionIdFieldOnlyIndexValue(true);
$this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('sellers');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it working with jquery by writing following code :

jQuery('a:contains("Select All")').click();

On the document ready in page  where you want to autoselect all items in a grid.

Comment: There is no template file for the grid..
I cant place this line and also I think that you did not got my question.

Comment: There is a PHTML for grid inside app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/massaction.phtml in which you can place the code i have suggested.

Comment: but I can't alter the base files of magento as I am using the grid in a module and there is no template file there for the grid.